# _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push does not work when saving sharepoint site

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, alert

I have created a method to validate input field in a share point site as you may see in the code below. 
The issue is that the method should be activated on saved, but it does not.
For now it is activated on document ready and that is not what I want. 
Any advice?

```
 </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function(){


 ValidateFields();

});

function ValidateFields()
{
 if ((document.querySelector('input[name$="BooleanField"]').checked ==false) 
 && ($("select[title='Employees selected values'] option").length==0)) 
 {
// $("select[title='Employees selected values'] option").length==0).text("<p> 
  Please check All employees in department OR select employees </p>");
  // // checked, so do something
  alert ("Please check All employees in department OR select employees")
 }

 if ((document.querySelector('input[name$="BooleanField"]').checked ==true) 
 && ($("select[title='Employees selected values'] option").length==1)) {


  alert ("Please check All employees in department OR select employees23")

 }



}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ValidateFields()");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use PreSaveAction method to achieve it. The following code for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveAction(){
    if ((document.querySelector('input[name$="BooleanField"]').checked ==false)&& ($("select[title='Employees selected values'] option").length==0)){
        // checked, so do something
        alert ("Please check All employees in department OR select employees");
        return false;
    }
    if ((document.querySelector('input[name$="BooleanField"]').checked ==true)&& ($("select[title='Employees selected values'] option").length==1)) {
        alert ("Please check All employees in department OR select employees23");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override the "Submit" handler of the form. Depending on the ID of your button, this might work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id$='SaveItem']").each(function() {

        // get the button
        var button = $(this);

        // reference the existing handler for later use
        var existingHandler = this.onclick;

        // clear the existing handler
        this.onclick = null;

        // add your custom handler that validates first, then "submits" if successful
        button.click(function() {
            if(ValidateFields()){ // change ValidateFields to return true/false
                 existingHandler(); // validation passed, now call original handler
            }
        });
    });
});
```